# Creating "objects" and "arrays" in PHP in a way that would allows JS to distinguish between them

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

PHP's syntax to create an array (either indexed or assosiative) is the same, aka

```
$arr = [];
```

However, `json_encode` will convert an empty PHP "array" (note the quotes) to an empty JS array (`[]`), which is not desirable in certain situations.

Is there a way I can create an empty assosiative array in PHP, so `json_encode` will convert it to an empty JS object, aka `{}`, instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `stdClass()`:

```
php > $x = new StdClass;
php > echo json_encode($x);
{}
```

Of course, once it's a stdclass, you wouldn't be able to use it as an array anymore. But this is at least one way of forcing an empty object in JSON, so you could just special-case your code:

```
if (count($array) == 0) {
   $json = json_encode(new StdClass);
} else {
    $json = json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Juuuust beat me by a second, dang. :)

Comment: Let me try how much MongoDB will tolerate that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
echo json_encode($obj);
```

This gets me the intended `{}` output.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option to the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. This will force any empty arrays to be objects as well.

> JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (integer) Outputs an object rather than an array
>   when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the
>   recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty.
>   Available since PHP 5.3.0.

So:

```
if (empty($array)) {
    $json = json_encode([], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
} else {
    $json = json_encode($array);
}
```

This looks cleaner than converting an object in my opinion.

Or even

```
$json = json_encode($array, empty($array) ? JSON_FORCE_OBJECT : 0);
```

Comment: Didn't know that--very handy!

Comment: Yeah, that that would make to real empry arrays to get convert to empty Objects too, which is not something I want to do.

Comment: A conditional could be used to solve that issue, but I understand.

Comment: @alexandernst Added the conditional that is required like the other solutions.